# The default Google Cloud SQL instance is not owned by any organization

Tags: sql, cloud, google-app-maker

[image]

Hi There,

We just have followed the steps as described in here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7550053, but still our appmaker is not able to load Google Cloud SQL. It's saying that our Cloud SQL instance is not owned by any organization.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A complete copy-paste of the exact error message is always better than an image. An image may sometimes add useful information, but text is primary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind! This issue is resolved as per Google Cloud Support answers. If anyone has the same problems you will find the solution doing this: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing